# WinSockServer and sql server Connection visual basic error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sockets

the socket receives customer information and should open connection to SQL Server at that time
sends visual studio error : 
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
Public dbconexion As SqlConnection
Dim WithEvents WinSockServer1 As New ServidorTCP.WinSockServer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With WinSockServer1

        .PuertoDeEscucha = 8050

        .Escuchar()

    End With
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

Private Sub WinSockServer1_DatosRecibidos(ByVal IDTerminal As System.Net.IPEndPoint) Handles WinSockServer1.DatosRecibidos
    dbconexion.Open()
```

Comment: I don't see where you called `New` on the `SqlConnection` object.

Comment: if I call it , if not I use the socket works perfectly

Comment: call what? I don't understand

Comment: if SQL Server connection is correct , the problem is when I use the socket

Comment: Right, if you don't initialize the `SqlConnection` object you will get that error. `Public dbconexion As New SqlConnection`